# Grouping equivalance row as 2D array in python for very large data set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

I have 100k rows and I want to group it as explained below in python. A simple python iteration takes lots of time. How to optimize it using any python ML library?

```
    [[1,2,3,4],[2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1],[2]...]

    Output
    [[0,5],[1,3]],[2,4],[6],[7]]

    Explanation:  index 0,5 have same list ;
                  index 1,3 have same list ;
                  index 2,4 have same list ; 
                  index 6 no match
```

I have 100k sub list and I want to group it as explained above in python.

Comment: Does ordering matter? Would [1,2,3] be considered the same as [2,1,3]?

Comment: Yes..It matters ..as list is replica of database in mycase

Comment: Typically how many elements do you have in each list? What could be the maximum value across all elements?

Comment: Pad your list to make a 2d array then use `numpy.unique(my_array,axis=1)` to find the unique ones and finally find the indices.

Comment: @Divakar..each list have 20 element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to transform the lists to tuples, and then just `groupby` and access the `.groups` attribute if you want to know the indices for each group

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [[1,2,3,4], [2,3], [1,2,3], [2,3],
                            [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1], [2], [2,2], [2,1,3]]})

df.groupby(df.vals.apply(tuple)).groups
#{(1,): Int64Index([6], dtype='int64'),
# (1, 2, 3): Int64Index([2, 4], dtype='int64'),
# (1, 2, 3, 4): Int64Index([0, 5], dtype='int64'),
# (2,): Int64Index([7], dtype='int64'),
# (2, 1, 3): Int64Index([9], dtype='int64'),
# (2, 2): Int64Index([8], dtype='int64'),
# (2, 3): Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')}
```

---

If you need that list of grouped indices, try something like:

```
df.reset_index().groupby(df.vals.apply(tuple))['index'].apply(list).sort_values().tolist()
#[[0, 5], [1, 3], [2, 4], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```